# Invalid token when using 001 in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.4

I've looked for a solution to this online but haven't found anything relevant. An assignment for my course requires me to make a program where the computer will try to guess a number the user has input. The number needs to be between 001 and 100, so I have started by trying to ensure the user can only input numbers within that range.

The code i have so far:

```
import random
code=(int(input("Input a three digit code. Must be more than 001 and less than 100.")))
print(code)
if (code < 001) or (code > 100): 
    print ("Invalid code")
elif (code > 001) or (code < 100):
    print ("Valid code")
```

It works fine with 001 changed to 1, but if i run it with 001 i get an Invalid Token error. 
This needs to be done in Python 3.4.3.
Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: dont you need a raw_input or whatever for int?

Comment: Nevermind just looked it up, input() works in python 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers can't have leading zeroes in Python. Leading zeroes were previously (Python 2) used to denote octal numerals. Since many people didn't know that and were confused why `070 == 56`, Python 3 made leading zeroes illegal.

You shouldn't be converting `code` to an integer - only store actual numbers (that you intend to do calculations with) in numerical variables. Keep the string:

```
while True:
    code = input("Input a three digit code. Must be more than 001 and less than 100.")
    try:
        value = int(code)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid code")
        continue
    if 1 <= value <= 100: 
        print ("Valid code")
        break
    else:
        print ("Invalid code")
```

Comment: You may want to use a better check than `"001" <= code <= "100"`. If I enter `0az` as code, it will be accepted. You will have to check that all chars are decimal digits.